# Facebook graph api posting comments and like

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph api in my app. I am able to get list of profile posts in UItableview.. I have called GetMeFeed() Method and passed array to next class like

```
FaceBookTable *detailViewController = [[FaceBookTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"FaceBookTable" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    detailViewController.dummyArray  =  friendsArray;
    detailViewController.nameArray = nameArray;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
```

In FacebookTable class I am displaying post message and id  using

```
cell.textLabel.text  = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];

//cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"]  ;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Now I want to comment on any of the post ... How can I do this .. I know the URL...

```
www.facebook.com/postId/comments
```

but how can make request from facebooktable class